# why does reading an array in parallel cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, valgrind, intrinsics

I am reading an array in parallel using openmp. Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  // align to cache line, which is 512 bits or 64 bytes
  size_t actualSize = 2048;

  uint8_t* array = static_cast<uint8_t *>(aligned_alloc(64, actualSize));
  for(size_t i = 0; i < actualSize; i++){
    // initialize values
    array[i] = rand() % 256;
  }

  __m256i sum_v = _mm256_setzero_si256 ();
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (size_t i = 0; i < actualSize; i+=32){
    __m256i v1 = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i *) array+i);
    // i understand that there is a race condition here, but I'm just
    // concerned with the memory leaks
    sum_v = _mm256_add_epi8 (sum_v, v1);
  }

  // just to keep compiler from optimizing out sum_v
  uint8_t result = _mm256_extract_epi8 (sum_v, 0);

  std::cout << "result: " << result << std::endl;

  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

This is an attempt to measure memory bandwidth on my computer, I will eventually time this for different actualSizes.

I compile this with `g++ -Wall -g -std=c++1y -march=native -mtune=native -fopenmp -O3 -g minimal-memleaks.cpp`. When I run this program using `valgrind ./a.out`, I get a memory leak, part of which is copied below

```
==7688== Thread 8:
==7688== Invalid read of size 32
==7688==    at 0x108D30: _mm256_add_epi8 (avx2intrin.h:107)
==7688==    by 0x108D30: main._omp_fn.0 (minimal-memleaks.cpp:25)
==7688==    by 0x51DB95D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==7688==    by 0x5FA66DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==7688==    by 0x551588E: clone (clone.S:95)
==7688==  Address 0x61e1980 is 29,280 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,077,760 in arena "client"
```

full output available here: https://pastebin.com/qr0W9FGD

I can't seem to see why. At first I thought the loop was going past the 2048 Bytes I allocated, but my math says it shouldn't. I read in blocks of 32, and adding 32 to i will eventually equal 2048, when the loop should stop. I also thought perhaps the main thread was closing before the child threads, but my research suggests that the main thread will not close until the threads created by the `#pragma omp parallel for` loop do. Is this incorrect?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: A memory leak is (roughly) having extra memory allocated that you no longer need and should have deallocated. This error says you're reading memory you shouldn't be reading.

Comment: pointer arithmetics: `(const __m256i *) array+i` is not where you expect it to be

Comment: In short, you are missing a set of parentheses around `array+i`, the cast is evaluated before the addition. Your thinking was just fine otherwise.

Comment: @Qubit your comment about order of operations is what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a memory leak. You're reading and/or corrupting memory.

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < actualSize; i+=32){
   __m256i v1 = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i *) array+i);
```

You're running off the end of the array, here. `actualSize` is the size of your allocated array ***in bytes***.

`__m256i` is a data type that's 32 bytes long.

```
(const __m256i *) array
```

This converts the pointer to a pointer to a 32 byte object.

The way that pointer addition works in C++, is that adding one to a pointer advances the pointer ***to the next object***, so

```
 array+1
```

is where the ***next***  32-byte object is. Which is 32 bytes after `array`.

So if you work out which addresses your `for` loop ends up reading, it should be obvious that it's running off the end of your array into never-never land, and valgrind barks at you because of that.

Your `for` loop should probably be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < actualSize/32; ++i){
  __m256i v1 = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i *) array+i);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it also be valid to do the following?
`for (size_t i = 0; i < actualSize; i+=32){
   __m256i v1 = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i *) (array+i));
}`
this way, array is incremented by `i` bytes before being cast?

Comment: Yes, and the compiler is likely to generate the same code.